# How does browser connect to nearest CDN server for a given CDN image url?

Tags: http, networking, dns, cdn, akamai

Lets say our browser is loading a post on facebook which has an image in it. The image has been stored in CDN(Content delivery network) by Facebook and its URL is given to the browser (eg: https://scontent-bom1-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/149815846_4027009347343846_8048150791219282631_o.jpg?_nc_cat=109&ccb=3&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=UcXY9DrL1DAAX8VQrTs&_nc_ht=scontent-bom1-2.xx&oh=da366f4d686fe03dc83123b35d21ac77&oe=604C5818)

Now, how does the browser connect to the nearest CDN server so that the image is loaded quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Akamai has a good blog post that explains this.
https://blogs.akamai.com/2013/03/intelligent-user-mapping-in-the-cloud.html